# x86/Linux multithreading: perf report children percentage sum does not match the parent percentage

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, x86, perf

Consider the following simple example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <linux/futex.h>

volatile atomic_int variable;
int futex_word;

int foo(void *v)
{
    while (1)
    {
        int expected = atomic_load(&variable);
        atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&variable, &expected, expected + 1);
        syscall(SYS_futex, &futex_word, FUTEX_WAKE, 1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    void *stack = (char *)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0) + 4096;
    clone(foo, stack, CLONE_CHILD_SETTID, NULL);
    sleep(1000);
}
```

Running this example with

```
sudo perf record --call-graph dwarf,16384 -F 9123 ./main
```

and then

```
sudo perf report
```

I got the following strange result I don't know who to interpret:

[image]

In the image the very first expanded symbol `foo` consists of 2 entries:

- `95.53% foo`
- `0.93% __GI___clone`

The problem I see here is `0.93% + 95.53% = 96.46%` which mismatches `96.52%` that is shown for the symbol `foo`.

Why there's such a mismatch? I see this pretty often when profiling different binaries, but not sure if it's possible to interpret it as a measurement error.

Comment: I notice that the next entry in the list *is* `96,46%` for `__GI___clone (inline)` with a self count of `0,00%`.  IDK what's up with that; it certainly looks like the numbers you added are supposed to be the breakdown for `foo`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Exactly, and the sum of `__GI___clone` and `foo` always matches the `__GI___clone (inline)` across different runs (I made around 20 runs). But it's always `0.05%` - `0.08%` mismatch for the parent value.